# how to check how many queryClient instances are created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

I'm handling a huge project where at some parts of the code `useQueryClient` is used to get the queryClient and other parts `new QueryClient()` is used, for reasons including the inability to call a react hook outside a function component or outside a custom hook

Will that create more than one instance of the queryClient? if yes,
Is there a way to check how many queryClient instances are created?

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
```

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always a bad idea to just call `new QueryClient()` - you can't really do anything with that. The `QueryClient` contains the `QueryCache`. If you create a new one, you have an empty cache. This cache will have no relation with the cache that any other parts of your app are using. Don't do that.

Calling `useQueryClient()` will give you the client that you've put into the `<QueryClientProvider>` - that's the one you want.

Now the question is: Why do you need the client outside of react? It's recommended to transform functions into hooks so that you can call `useQueryClient()`. In my experience, that works 95% of the time.

If not, you should use *the same* instance of a client that you created and put into the Provider. You can always export it and import it directly if you want.

More on this here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#why-should-i-usequeryclient